# How can i recognize two picture are same?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

for example i have a image dataset. I used these images for train my model, and I am using another image for test. How can i recognize the test image is on the dataset? How do I determine what the similarity percentage is?

Answer (score 0):

you can try correlation on both images if there exactly the same should get 1

Comment: I have a audio dataset and i plot the spectrogram. I want to recognize the similarity percentage.